# How to create a multi part form or wizard in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to follow a few UI/UX best practices when developing a simple "request quote" form for my users.

I basically want them to fill only a few fields at a time as I guide them through it, giving them some feedback or update on cost depending on what they fill. And this is the important part, I only want to upload/save to the backend only once the user finished the whole wizard and clicks on "Complete" in the last panel. I don't want to have partial/unfinished "Quote" objects.

1) I have setup a navigation controller and added a few UIViewControllers with some fields, and I can basically step through them. Adding validation to the fields before jumping to the next field is no problem.

2) I use parse.com as my backend, and I have a "Quote" object, for simplicity's sake, let's say it has the following properties: firstName, lastName, location, date, options, price.

> I ask for location and date first > then first and last name > then
>   options > I then calculate a price and show it to him/her > Then the user
>   can submit the whole thing to the server.

I looked around, and only found some indication to use a temporary xml file, which I then upload. Other results mainly pertain about http multi part requests, which I don't think relate.

Would core data be the ideal usage here? Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a `Quote` class that acts as your domain model? Don't store something like this in core data or temporary xml files.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, right, just create an instance and populate it as I go, and then push it in the end. Sometimes I forget how to think straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is best used for local persistence of data, what you are doing is just capturing data to post to an REST url. Create an class that holds your data and pass it from view controller a to view controller b, etc. At the end, make the call to parse.com and submit your data. You can either add the logic to communicate to parse in your final view controller or put it a separate class.

If you want the user to be able to come back to the quote, then Core Data would be good to use.